# Cauchy estimates consequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D\subseteq\Bbb C$ open, $f:D\to\Bbb C$ holomorphic. Let $K\Subset D$ compact subset of $\Bbb C$ contained in $D$, such that its boundary $\partial K$ is the disjoint union of a finite number of $\mathcal{C}^1$ piecewise paths in $D$.

It is well known that
$$
f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial K}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}\,d\zeta
\;\;,\;\;\forall z\in\stackrel{\circ}{K}
$$
thus
$$
(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;|f^{(n)}(z)|\le\frac{n!}{2\pi}\frac{||f||_{\partial K}}{[\operatorname{dist}(z,\partial K)]^{n+1}}L(\partial K)\;\;,\;\;\forall z\in\stackrel{\circ}{K}$$
where
$L(\partial K)$ is the sum of the lenght of the finite number of piecewise $\mathcal{C}^1$ paths which forms $\partial K$.

And till here it's all clear. But my teacher wrote that from this last estimate follows the next one:
$$
(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;||f^{(n)}||_{K}\le \alpha||f||_D
$$
where $\alpha$ is some positive real constant (he didn't wrote any dependance of this constant from any parameter such as $n$). Taking the supremum on $K$ in $(1)$, the denominator of RHS should go to zero because $z$ can go as near as we want to $\partial K$, thus it wouldn't help to understand how to get $(2)$. Or maybe to correct it.

Can someone help me? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

If you have a compact set $K$ and an open set $D$ in a metric space such that $K\subseteq D$ you can show $\text{dist}(K,D^c>0)$, so for example if $ K$ is a closed ball you can find a bigger closed ball $\overline K$ with same midcenter that still lies in $D$.Then you can let your path go arround $\partial \overline K$ and do your estimatation.